# How to show fullscreen popovercontroller in iPhone screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipopovercontroller

I have UIbarbuttonItem in navationbar and than click the button works well iPad simulator but don't work iPhone simulator because Popover not supported iPhone. I trying to show fullscreen popovercontroller in iPhone screen.How to fix this problem. I add my codes and screenshots. 
Thanks in advance.
MyCodes;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIBarButtonItem *shareItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *cameraItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *searchItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    NSArray *actionButtonItems = @[shareItem, cameraItem, flexibleItem,searchItem];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if(![popoverController isPopoverVisible]){
        UIViewController *viewControllerForPopover = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
        popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewControllerForPopover];
        popoverController.delegate=self;
        [popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        //popoverController.passthroughViews=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.view, nil];
    }
    else{

        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }


}

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIPopoverControllerDelegate,UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate>{

    UIPopoverController *popoverController;

    CameraViewController *cameraPopOver;
}
```

My Screens;
[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't show a popover in an iPhone app since, as you've already noted, it's not supported at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, Can I show fullscreen in iphone ? Normally,when I use  Popoversegue,Screen show fullscreen in iphone.

Comment: Oh, yeah... It used to do that during some Xcode 6 beta versions, but it doesn't do that anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I once used [KGModal](https://github.com/kgn/KGModal).

KGModal is an easy drop in control that allows you to display any view in a modal popup. Can popup UIView and UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

PopoverController can't be added to iPhone as this controller is only for iPad and not for iOS. to solve your issue you can take a simple view or a tableview over there, which will appear on click event of bar button